# Clearfix issues Bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Got overlap issues on a panels column. Content is running into footer on LARGE and MID SCREEN SIZES. Tried clearfix visible-xs-block as well as md-block and lg-block but nothing works.

```
<div class="panel panel-default clearfix visible-md-block">
```

see: http://howlingwolfmedia.com/dev/jrmasonry_btstrp/
The overlap occurs on right column in large and med screens only (not <768).

Also tried adding clearfix to footer tag:

```
 <footer class="row clearfix center-block">
      <p>content here</p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Try wrapping the <footer> in <div class="row"></div> tags and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove `bannerbottom` from `<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7">` You should add the background-image as an element inside the col-md-7.

[image]

Comment: Kind of defeats point of  design.  If you resize your browser you'll see bannerbottom is responsive; 1size for dsktp, another for mid-size (e.g. landscape ipad)
...media screen and (min-width: 1170px) -> width: 1170px; height:187...Another for ...media screen and (min-width: 1024px) ->
        height: 187px;}
Still not sure why the overflow based on this design but thanks for pointing out the problem. Need to research further a solution. Trying to push design responsive is challenging.

Comment: You can use this as a div inside the col-md-7 :) And position it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This did the trick.
`  <div class=" col-lg-7  col-md-7    nopad ">
      <div class="bannerbottom">
      </div>`